# script to calculate the average

Tags: text-processing

We have a big file in which three columns are there that is hour, response time and service name. These fields are separated by space. We need write a script to calculate the number of occurrence of the service name on an hourly basis and find the average of response time.

A piece of file is shown below.

```
15 999 createLead
15 999 getLead
15 999 jointCall
15 999 searchLead
16 1002 jointCall
16 1019 createLead
16 1031 jointCall
16 1032 jointCall
16 1040 jointCall
16 1044 jointCall
17 1011 createLead
17 1027 createLead
17 189 getLTSUserDetails
19 1439 searchLead
19 1708 searchFileStatus
19 1832 updateLead
```

Comment: the only advise I have for you is: Do not use perl, synthax is awful you can do the same thing in hundreds way with side effects... But that's only my personnal thougts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk**

```
awk '
    {
    task[$3,$1] += $2
    count[$3,$1] += 1
    }
    END {
        for (t in task) {
            split(t, tHour, "\034");
            print tHour[1] " " tHour[2] " " count[t] " " task[t] / count[t]
        }
    }
' yourFile
```

**Result**

Task, Hour, Num of occurrence, Average of response time

```
searchFileStatus 19 1 1708
searchLead 19 1 1439
getLead 15 1 999
jointCall 15 1 999
jointCall 16 5 1029.8
updateLead 19 1 1832
createLead 15 1 999
createLead 16 1 1019
getLTSUserDetails 17 1 189
createLead 17 2 1019
searchLead 15 1 999
```

Previous attempt:

**awk**

```
awk '
    {
    task[$3] += $2
    count[$3] += 1
    }
    END {
        for (t in task) {
            print t " " count[t] " " task[t] / count[t]
        }
    }
' yourFile
```

**Result**

Task, Num of occurrence, Average of response time

```
updateLead 1 1832
jointCall 6 1024.67
getLead 1 999
getLTSUserDetails 1 189
createLead 4 1014
searchLead 2 1219
searchFileStatus 1 1708
```